# How to get difference between two *.sql files using difflib

Tags: python, sql

I would like to get difference between two .sql files as mentioned in the output below. I am able to generate the differences using difflib with '+' and '-'. But for any datatype changes , I want to get as '!', how to achieve the same in python.

### file1.sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE  (
       'emp_name' VARCHAR(255),
       'emp_sal' SHORT INT,
        'address VARCHAR(255));
```

### file2.sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE  (
       'emp_name' VARCHAR(255),
       'emp_sal' INT,
       'job' VARCHAR default 1);
```

### Expected Output or Change Log

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE  (
       'emp_name' VARCHAR(255),

       !'emp_sal' INT,

       +'job' VARCHAR default 1,

       - 'address VARCHAR(255));
```

Above the emp_sal datatype is modified, I want to get output as !emp_sal int rather than '+'

### My Program

```
import difflib, optparse

def main():
    # Configure the option parser
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] fromfile tofile"
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-u", action="store_true", default=False,
         help='Produce a unified format diff')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) == 0:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

    if len(args) != 2:
        parser.error("need to specify both a fromfile and tofile")

    fromfile, tofile = args # as specified in the usage string

    fromlines = open(fromfile, 'U').readlines()
    tolines = open(tofile, 'U').readlines()
    targetfile = open('diff_of_files.sql', 'w')

    diff = difflib.unified_diff(fromlines, tolines, n=2)
    diff = list(diff)[2:]

    for i in diff:
        targetfile.writelines(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

CREATE TABLE Persons
 (
  'emp_name' VARCHAR(255),

**+**'emp_sal' INT,**  **>> expecting as ! instead of +**

**+**'job' VARCHAR default 1,

**-** 'address VARCHAR(255));

Comment: do you want to detect only changes in datatype?

Comment: I would need to identify particular modification of any data type as well as the new lines and deleted lines

Comment: Look at the answer I have given. It's been a long time I have answered it. If you don't really need help, you shouldn't have asked in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does the job you want:

```
import difflib
import optparse
import sys


def main():
    # Configure the option parser
    usage = "usage: %prog [options] fromfile tofile"
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-u", action="store_true", default=False,
                      help='Produce a unified format diff')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) == 0:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

    if len(args) != 2:
        parser.error("need to specify both a fromfile and tofile")

    fromfile, tofile = args  # as specified in the usage string

    rawfromlines = open(fromfile, 'U').readlines()
    rawtolines = open(tofile, 'U').readlines()

    fromlines, tolines = [], []

    for fl in rawfromlines:
        for part in fl.replace('\n', '').split(','):
            fromlines.append(part)

    for tl in rawtolines:
        for part in tl.replace('\n', '').split(','):
            tolines.append(part)

    targetfile = open('diff_of_files.sql', 'w')

    differ = difflib.Differ()
    diffs = list(differ.compare(fromlines, tolines))
    lines = []

    length = len(diffs)
    i = 0
    while i < length:
        if diffs[i].startswith('  '):
            lines.append('  ' + diffs[i][2:])
        elif diffs[i].startswith('+ '):
            lines.append('+ ' + diffs[i][2:])
        elif diffs[i].startswith('- '):
            try:
                if diffs[i + 1].startswith('? ') and diffs[i + 2].startswith('+ '):
                    lines.append('! ' + diffs[i][2:] + ' --> ' + diffs[i+2][2:].strip())
                    i += 2
                elif diffs[i + 1].startswith('+ ') and diffs[i + 2].startswith('? '):
                    lines.append('! ' + diffs[i][2:] + ' --> ' + diffs[i+1][2:])
                    i += 2
                else:
                    lines.append('- ' + diffs[i][2:])
            except IndexError:
                lines.append('- ' + diffs[i][2:])
        i += 1

    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('  CREATE'):
            stripped_line = line.strip()
        else:
            stripped_line = line.rstrip()
        if stripped_line:
            targetfile.write(stripped_line+'\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is not working .. Once you are free, could you please send me the updated program.

Comment: What is 'not working'? You should provide some details as to what is not working. I have tweaked the code a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Due to some indentation issues it doesn't work earlier.. Now i executed properly and it is working.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried with some more scenarios of data, but the algorithm which was mentioned above is not working..for example:CREATE TABLE Persons
(
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar2(255),
PersonID int,
Address varchar(255),
JobDetails short int
);

CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY int
);

CREATE TABLE JOB
(
 EMP int
);
file2.sql -> CREATE TABLE Persons
(
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
PersonID short int,
JobDetails int
);
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
PersonID short int,
LastName varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY int
 BEN    int
);

Comment: edit your question with example of input files content **as they are formatted** in your files, and sample output **formatted correctly** as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your above program. I tweaked the above program and it worked.